# Why can "earthquake crack makes monumental mortal" here?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

In *THE SAINT* by *V.S. Pritchett*:

> I saw the shoes dip, water rise above his ankles and up his socks. He tried to move his grip now to a yet higher branch. He did not succeed, and in making this effort, his coat and waist-coat rose and parted from his trousers. One seam of shirt with its pant-loops and brace-tabs broke like a crack across the middle of Mr. Timberlake. ***It was like a fatal flaw in a statue, an earthquake crack which made the monumental mortal.*** The last Greeks must have felt as I felt then, when they saw a crack across the middle of some statue of Apollo. It was at this moment I realized that the final revelation about man and society on earth had come to nobody and that Mr. Timberlake knew nothing at all about the origin of evil.

I suppose "monumental mortal" = "monumental statue of a mortal" in the bolded sentence, but why is it "made" by the earthquake crack?  I could understand the whole sentence(probably means an earthquake crack on a monumental statue of a mortal), but the "made" part is confusing to me.

Comment: Makes **the** monumental mortal - makes that which is monumental mortal (subject to damage, toppling, etc).

Comment: In the cited context, ***the monumental*** is like ***The poor** [are always with us]*. Just as ***the poor*** means ***people** who are poor*, so ***the monumental*** means ***things** which are monumental* (impressively large and/or long-lasting, like a monument). So to some extent, monumental things (like a stone carved statue) could be called "immortal", but not if there's a crack in the stone. That crack could destroy the statue, making it "mortal = subject to death and decay".

Comment: Timberlake's shirt hanging out of his trousers is a "fatal flaw" that "cuts him down to size". If it weren't for that he would be a very imposing figure, but his shirt hanging out is a clear indication that *he puts his pants on one leg at a time*, just like all us "ordinary mortals".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Mortal" is simply describing what the "monumental" thing was made into. That part of the sentence does not actually refer to a statue, it refers to some monumental thing in general.

Consider an easier example:

> Eating berries **made** *her tongue* purple.

Her tongue was *made* (caused to become) purple. What caused this? Eating berries.

Your sentence is more complex and confusing because "the monumental" (referring to some generic monumental **thing**) is very similar to "the monument" (referring to a specific object) and because "mortal" is not something that people or objects generally *become*. But it uses the same structure:

> An earthquake crack **made** *the monumental* mortal.

The monumental [thing] was caused to become mortal. What caused this? An earthquake crack.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you're interpreting it right - in your interpretation *(the) mortal* is a noun and *monumental* is an adjective modifying it, but while this is grammatically sound it does not really make sense in context.

Instead, *(the) monumental* functions as a noun, and *mortal* is an adjective. As such, the earthquake takes *the monumental* (something grandiose, eternal) and makes it *mortal* (subject to death and decay, no longer special). It's a similar construction to, eg. *It made John angry*.